# AM335x - Custom Board <SEGV> when running Systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, kernel, u-boot, segmentation-fault

I tried asking my question on TI's forum, but I am not getting much feedback, so I thought I'd try my luck here.

You can see my ongoing discussion with TI here: https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors-group/processors/f/processors-forum/1158936/am3359-caught-segv-when-distro-s-systemd-starting

We have been working with the TI AM335x-ICEV2 board for some time now to develop an embedded Linux Application and received our own custom board design. After a lot of debugging and reading, I am able to make U-Boot load properly and then I went on to load the kernel with a very basic FDT (run-time configuration of U-Boot via a flattened devicetree) which seems to work, but as soon as I reach the distribution booting stage, I get segmentation fault on segmentation fault and/or freezing execution.

At first we suspected hardware issue with the DDR3 mapping, but the design seems to respect all of TI's requirements. Also the freeze/segv always happens during distribution boot. I have never seen a single crash/freeze/segv during U-Boot or Linux Kernel bootings.

The only successful configuration I could get to boot, is the Tiny Filesystem from TI-Linux-SDK that uses SysVinit and loads no module at all. Any systemd os has failed so far (Debian and Arago) and I tried replacing Systemd by a SysV in an existing Debian 10 image, but it failed.

Although the same Uboot + Kernel runs perfectly on a TI IceV2 dev. board.

I am far from being a Linux Bootloader/Kernel pro and I am running out of theories on what could cause this issue or even what tests to run. If someone is willing to answer a few questions, I am more than willing to share some data.

**Here is my console output when booting:**

*I removed this one for an updated one beneath, due to the limit of characters.*

**And here is my FDT File:**

```
/dts-v1/;

#include "am33xx.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "AM335x HELLO";
    compatible = "ti,am335x-hello", "ti,am33xx";

    chosen {
        stdout-path = &uart3;
        tick-timer = &timer2;
    };

    memory {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x80000000 0x10000000>; /* 256 MB */
    };

    vbat: fixedregulator@0 {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        regulator-name = "vbat";
        regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-boot-on;
    };

    vmmc: fixedregulator@1 {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        regulator-name = "vmmc";
        regulator-min-microvolt = <3300000>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <3300000>;
        regulator-always-on;
        regulator-boot-on;
    };
};

&am33xx_pinmux {
    mmc0_pins_default: mmc0_pins_default {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_MMC0_DAT3, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE0)
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_MMC0_DAT2, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE0)
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_MMC0_DAT1, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE0)
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_MMC0_DAT0, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE0)
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_MMC0_CLK, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE0)
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_MMC0_CMD, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE0)
        >;
    };

    uart1_pins: uart1_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            0x180 (PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE0)    /* uart1_rxd.uart1_rxd */
            0x184 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE0) /* uart1_txd.uart1_txd */
        >;
    };
};

&uart1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&uart1_pins>;
    status = "okay";
};

&mmc1 {
    status = "okay";
    vmmc-supply = <&vmmc>;
    bus-width = <4>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&mmc0_pins_default>;
};
```

**EDIT #1**
Initialisation Logs do not always crash/freeze at the same place. here is another one but with U-Boot *optargs* **printk.devkmsg=on systemd.log_level=debug debug**:

```
[    2.175611] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    2.863478] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    2.996170] systemd[1]: systemd 241 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    3.018180] systemd[1]: No virtualization found in DMI
[    3.023569] systemd[1]: No virtualization found in CPUID
[    3.028969] systemd[1]: Virtualization XEN not found, /proc/xen does not exist
[    3.036559] systemd[1]: No virtualization found in /proc/device-tree/*
[    3.043420] systemd[1]: UML virtualization not found in /proc/cpuinfo.
[    3.050020] systemd[1]: This platform does not support /proc/sysinfo
[    3.056508] systemd[1]: Found VM virtualization none
[    3.061529] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    3.067154] systemd[1]: Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event of type cgroup with options perf_event.
[    3.078818] systemd[1]: Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio of type cgroup with options blkio.
[    3.089463] systemd[1]: Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct of type cgroup with options cpu,cpuacct.
[    3.101298] systemd[1]: Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer of type cgroup with options freezer.
[    3.112236] systemd[1]: Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/memory of type cgroup with options memory.
[    3.123482] systemd[1]: Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/devices of type cgroup with options devices.
[    3.134395] systemd[1]: Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/pids of type cgroup with options pids.
[    3.144778] systemd[1]: Mounting cgroup to /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls of type cgroup with options net_cls.

Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)!

[    3.184740] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <arm>.
[    3.197755] systemd[1]: Successfully added address 127.0.0.1 to loopback interface
[    3.205882] systemd[1]: Successfully added address ::1 to loopback interface
[    3.213414] systemd[1]: Successfully brought loopback interface up
[    3.220179] systemd[1]: Setting 'fs/file-max' to '2147483647'.
[    3.230141] systemd[1]: Found cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified, unified hierarchy for systemd controller
[    3.240134] systemd[1]: Unified cgroup hierarchy is located at /sys/fs/cgroup/unified. Controllers are on legacy hierarchies.
[    3.258918] systemd[1]: Can't allocate BPF LPM TRIE map, BPF firewalling is not supported: Function not implemented
[    3.269658] systemd[1]: Can't load kernel CGROUP DEVICE BPF program, BPF device control is not supported: Function not implemented
[    3.281537] systemd[1]: Controller 'cpu' supported: yes
[    3.286948] systemd[1]: Controller 'cpuacct' supported: yes
[    3.292562] systemd[1]: Controller 'io' supported: no
[    3.297676] systemd[1]: Controller 'blkio' supported: yes
[    3.303132] systemd[1]: Controller 'memory' supported: yes
[    3.308654] systemd[1]: Controller 'devices' supported: yes
[    3.314306] systemd[1]: Controller 'pids' supported: yes
[    3.319657] systemd[1]: Controller 'bpf-firewall' supported: no
[    3.325634] systemd[1]: Controller 'bpf-devices' supported: no
[    3.331602] systemd[1]: Set up TFD_TIMER_CANCEL_ON_SET timerfd.
[    3.339066] systemd[1]: Enabling showing of status.
[    3.345654] systemd[1]: Successfully forked off '(sd-executor)' as PID 55.
[    3.358258] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 56.
[    3.373243] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 57.
[    3.381122] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 58.
[    3.434440] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 59.
[    3.442219] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 60.
[    3.504363] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 61.
[    3.512081] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 62.
[    3.634380] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 63.
[    3.642125] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 64.
[    3.744461] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 65.
[    3.752179] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 66.
[    3.866714] systemd[55]: Successfully forked off '(direxec)' as PID 67.
[    3.923497] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-rc-local-generator terminated by signal SEGV.
[    3.971004] systemd-hibernate-resume-generator[62]: Not running in an initrd, quitting.
[    4.046186] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-hibernate-resume-generator succeeded.
[    4.080695] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-gpt-auto-generator terminated by signal SEGV.
[    4.110089] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-getty-generator failed with exit status 127.
[    4.121572] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-cryptsetup-generator succeeded.
[    4.130888] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for sendsigs.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.142139] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Cannot find unit udhcpd.service.
[    4.149412] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for bootlogs.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.159691] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Cannot find unit cpufrequtils.service.
[    4.170591] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for procps.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.179985] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for checkroot.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.189433] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for urandom.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.200115] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for rcS.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.211224] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for kmod.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.220302] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for checkfs.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.229691] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Cannot find unit loadcpufreq.service.
[    4.237351] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for rc.local.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.248773] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for udev.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.257901] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for bluetooth.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.268275] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for rsyslog.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.277771] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Cannot find unit exim4.service.
[    4.284927] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for umountroot.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.294421] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for halt.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.303444] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for mountnfs-bootclean.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.313619] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for hostname.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.324009] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for avahi-daemon.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.333755] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for mountall.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.343999] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for ofono.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.354101] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for connman.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.363490] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for mountkernfs.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.372965] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for reboot.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.382251] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for hostapd.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.391633] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for hwclock.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.400903] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for rmnologin.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.411226] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for dnsmasq.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.420535] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for mountdevsubfs.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.431225] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for dbus.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.440317] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for umountfs.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.450598] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for cron.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.459795] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for sudo.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.468808] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for mountall-bootclean.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.479086] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for mountnfs.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.488424] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for brightness.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.498809] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for dundee.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.507999] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for umountnfs.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.517566] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for rc.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.527371] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for ssh.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.536340] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for checkroot-bootclean.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.546706] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for apache-htcacheclean.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.557047] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for single.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.567119] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for rsync.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.576220] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for killprocs.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.586582] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for networking.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.596250] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for apache2.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.605557] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Native unit for bootmisc.service already exists, skipping.
[    4.616340] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S02single symlink in rc1.d, not generating single.service.
[    4.626331] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01killprocs symlink in rc1.d, not generating killprocs.service.
[    4.636740] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01bootlogs symlink in rc1.d, not generating bootlogs.service.
[    4.648331] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01rsyslog symlink in rc2.d, not generating rsyslog.service.
[    4.658459] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04ofono symlink in rc2.d, not generating ofono.service.
[    4.668189] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03ssh symlink in rc2.d, not generating ssh.service.
[    4.677527] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01rsync symlink in rc2.d, not generating rsync.service.
[    4.687190] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04dundee symlink in rc2.d, not generating dundee.service.
[    4.697047] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01hostapd symlink in rc2.d, not generating hostapd.service.
[    4.707054] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03rsync symlink in rc2.d, not generating rsync.service.
[    4.716720] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03rmnologin symlink in rc2.d, not generating rmnologin.service.
[    4.727116] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01cron symlink in rc2.d, not generating cron.service.
[    4.736608] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01apache2 symlink in rc2.d, not generating apache2.service.
[    4.746613] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01ssh symlink in rc2.d, not generating ssh.service.
[    4.755960] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01sudo symlink in rc2.d, not generating sudo.service.
[    4.765522] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01bluetooth symlink in rc2.d, not generating bluetooth.service.
[    4.775884] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01ofono symlink in rc2.d, not generating ofono.service.
[    4.785583] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04bluetooth symlink in rc2.d, not generating bluetooth.service.
[    4.795942] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S02apache2 symlink in rc2.d, not generating apache2.service.
[    4.805969] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01connman symlink in rc2.d, not generating connman.service.
[    4.815976] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04connman symlink in rc2.d, not generating connman.service.
[    4.826024] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S05rc.local symlink in rc2.d, not generating rc.local.service.
[    4.836208] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01dundee symlink in rc2.d, not generating dundee.service.
[    4.846062] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01bootlogs symlink in rc2.d, not generating bootlogs.service.
[    4.856258] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01avahi-daemon symlink in rc2.d, not generating avahi-daemon.service.
[    4.867164] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04avahi-daemon symlink in rc2.d, not generating avahi-daemon.service.
[    4.878058] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01dbus symlink in rc2.d, not generating dbus.service.
[    4.887561] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03dbus symlink in rc2.d, not generating dbus.service.
[    4.897057] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03cron symlink in rc2.d, not generating cron.service.
[    4.907950] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01rsyslog symlink in rc3.d, not generating rsyslog.service.
[    4.918100] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04ofono symlink in rc3.d, not generating ofono.service.
[    4.927809] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03ssh symlink in rc3.d, not generating ssh.service.
[    4.937169] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01rsync symlink in rc3.d, not generating rsync.service.
[    4.946831] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04dundee symlink in rc3.d, not generating dundee.service.
[    4.956668] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01hostapd symlink in rc3.d, not generating hostapd.service.
[    4.966695] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03rsync symlink in rc3.d, not generating rsync.service.
[    4.976358] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03rmnologin symlink in rc3.d, not generating rmnologin.service.
[    4.986727] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01cron symlink in rc3.d, not generating cron.service.
[    4.996231] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01apache2 symlink in rc3.d, not generating apache2.service.
[    5.006237] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01ssh symlink in rc3.d, not generating ssh.service.
[    5.015561] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01sudo symlink in rc3.d, not generating sudo.service.
[    5.025108] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01bluetooth symlink in rc3.d, not generating bluetooth.service.
[    5.035470] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01ofono symlink in rc3.d, not generating ofono.service.
[    5.045144] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04bluetooth symlink in rc3.d, not generating bluetooth.service.
[    5.055522] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S02apache2 symlink in rc3.d, not generating apache2.service.
[    5.065531] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01connman symlink in rc3.d, not generating connman.service.
[    5.075557] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04connman symlink in rc3.d, not generating connman.service.
[    5.085585] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S05rc.local symlink in rc3.d, not generating rc.local.service.
[    5.095786] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01dundee symlink in rc3.d, not generating dundee.service.
[    5.105621] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01bootlogs symlink in rc3.d, not generating bootlogs.service.
[    5.115840] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01avahi-daemon symlink in rc3.d, not generating avahi-daemon.service.
[    5.126722] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04avahi-daemon symlink in rc3.d, not generating avahi-daemon.service.
[    5.137635] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01dbus symlink in rc3.d, not generating dbus.service.
[    5.147118] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03dbus symlink in rc3.d, not generating dbus.service.
[    5.156631] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03cron symlink in rc3.d, not generating cron.service.
[    5.167496] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01rsyslog symlink in rc4.d, not generating rsyslog.service.
[    5.177641] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04ofono symlink in rc4.d, not generating ofono.service.
[    5.187344] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03ssh symlink in rc4.d, not generating ssh.service.
[    5.196702] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01rsync symlink in rc4.d, not generating rsync.service.
[    5.206365] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04dundee symlink in rc4.d, not generating dundee.service.
[    5.216198] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01hostapd symlink in rc4.d, not generating hostapd.service.
[    5.226224] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03rsync symlink in rc4.d, not generating rsync.service.
[    5.235886] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03rmnologin symlink in rc4.d, not generating rmnologin.service.
[    5.246259] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01cron symlink in rc4.d, not generating cron.service.
[    5.255763] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01apache2 symlink in rc4.d, not generating apache2.service.
[    5.265771] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01ssh symlink in rc4.d, not generating ssh.service.
[    5.275106] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01sudo symlink in rc4.d, not generating sudo.service.
[    5.284660] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01bluetooth symlink in rc4.d, not generating bluetooth.service.
[    5.295023] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01ofono symlink in rc4.d, not generating ofono.service.
[    5.304697] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04bluetooth symlink in rc4.d, not generating bluetooth.service.
[    5.315074] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S02apache2 symlink in rc4.d, not generating apache2.service.
[    5.325082] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01connman symlink in rc4.d, not generating connman.service.
[    5.335108] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04connman symlink in rc4.d, not generating connman.service.
[    5.345135] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S05rc.local symlink in rc4.d, not generating rc.local.service.
[    5.355336] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01dundee symlink in rc4.d, not generating dundee.service.
[    5.365172] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01bootlogs symlink in rc4.d, not generating bootlogs.service.
[    5.375388] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01avahi-daemon symlink in rc4.d, not generating avahi-daemon.service.
[    5.386269] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04avahi-daemon symlink in rc4.d, not generating avahi-daemon.service.
[    5.397180] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01dbus symlink in rc4.d, not generating dbus.service.
[    5.406664] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03dbus symlink in rc4.d, not generating dbus.service.
[    5.416178] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03cron symlink in rc4.d, not generating cron.service.
[    5.426959] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01rsyslog symlink in rc5.d, not generating rsyslog.service.
[    5.437110] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04ofono symlink in rc5.d, not generating ofono.service.
[    5.446818] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03ssh symlink in rc5.d, not generating ssh.service.
[    5.456174] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01rsync symlink in rc5.d, not generating rsync.service.
[    5.465836] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04dundee symlink in rc5.d, not generating dundee.service.
[    5.475671] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01hostapd symlink in rc5.d, not generating hostapd.service.
[    5.485698] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03rsync symlink in rc5.d, not generating rsync.service.
[    5.495360] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03rmnologin symlink in rc5.d, not generating rmnologin.service.
[    5.505731] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01cron symlink in rc5.d, not generating cron.service.
[    5.515235] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01apache2 symlink in rc5.d, not generating apache2.service.
[    5.525241] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01ssh symlink in rc5.d, not generating ssh.service.
[    5.534565] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01sudo symlink in rc5.d, not generating sudo.service.
[    5.544117] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01bluetooth symlink in rc5.d, not generating bluetooth.service.
[    5.554480] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01ofono symlink in rc5.d, not generating ofono.service.
[    5.564153] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04bluetooth symlink in rc5.d, not generating bluetooth.service.
[    5.574532] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S02apache2 symlink in rc5.d, not generating apache2.service.
[    5.584540] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01connman symlink in rc5.d, not generating connman.service.
[    5.594567] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04connman symlink in rc5.d, not generating connman.service.
[    5.604592] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S05rc.local symlink in rc5.d, not generating rc.local.service.
[    5.614792] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01dundee symlink in rc5.d, not generating dundee.service.
[    5.624629] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01bootlogs symlink in rc5.d, not generating bootlogs.service.
[    5.634845] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01avahi-daemon symlink in rc5.d, not generating avahi-daemon.service.
[    5.645726] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S04avahi-daemon symlink in rc5.d, not generating avahi-daemon.service.
[    5.656638] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S01dbus symlink in rc5.d, not generating dbus.service.
[    5.666122] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03dbus symlink in rc5.d, not generating dbus.service.
[    5.675635] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Ignoring S03cron symlink in rc5.d, not generating cron.service.
[    5.685319] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Loading SysV script /etc/init.d/udhcpd
[    5.694263] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Loading SysV script /etc/init.d/exim4
[    5.705397] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Loading SysV script /etc/init.d/loadcpufreq
[    5.716624] systemd-sysv-generator[66]: Loading SysV script /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils
[    5.731392] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-sysv-generator succeeded.
[    5.739965] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-debug-generator succeeded.
[    5.748639] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-run-generator succeeded.
[    5.757026] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-veritysetup-generator terminated by signal SEGV.
[    5.767390] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-bless-boot-generator terminated by signal SEGV.
[    5.777681] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-system-update-generator succeeded.
[    5.786799] systemd[55]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator terminated by signal SEGV.
[    5.797673] systemd[1]: (sd-executor) succeeded.
[    5.802788] systemd[1]: Looking for unit files in (higher priority first):
[    5.809936] systemd[1]:      /etc/systemd/system.control
[    5.815015] systemd[1]:      /run/systemd/system.control
[    5.820012] systemd[1]:      /run/systemd/transient
[    5.824629] systemd[1]:      /etc/systemd/system
[    5.828928] systemd[1]:      /run/systemd/system
```

I can't seem to find the constant between each boots, except that it crashes...

*EDIT 2*:
Expected Dev board output is:

```
Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)! 
[ 6.828019] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <arm>. 
[ 7.793038] systemd[1]: File /lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service:12 configures an IP fire wall (IPAddressDeny=any), but the local system does not support BPF/cgroup based firewalling. 
[ 7.810794] systemd[1]: Proceeding WITHOUT firewalling in effect! (This warning is only shown for the first loaded unit using IP firewalling.) 
[ 8.292129] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket. 
[ OK ] Listening on udev Control Socket. 
...
(and so on)
```

Not that using a SySVInit environment with no modules, I can boot to the shell, but then some commands can cause a freeze.

Comment: Any idea why the output gets so silent after `[    1.801568]`? How does that compare to the dev board output?

Comment: That is an interesting observation. My idea is that this is where the segmentation fault and it hangs for some times before realizing the process is stuck. But actually, I do not always freeze at the same step of OS initialisation.

Comment: Also the dev board outputs is this:
Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)!

[    6.828019] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <arm>.
[    7.793038] systemd[1]: File /lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service:12 configures an IP fire
wall (IPAddressDeny=any), but the local system does not support BPF/cgroup based firewalling.
[    7.810794] systemd[1]: Proceeding WITHOUT firewalling in effect! (This warning is only shown for 
the first loaded unit using IP firewalling.)
[    8.292129] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Control Socket.
 (and more)

Comment: Interesting fact: Using "set optargs -b" in uboot, I can actually enter recovery mode and therefore access a Shell and use cd/ls/lsmod ,etc. Although I have to be careful because using things like nano freezes my interface. But even -b sometimes crashes before reaching the shell.

Comment: I suggest to edit the question and include this information, because (1) it's easier to read the output then and (2) this will make the question appear on top of the question list again finally (3) this is how this site works with everything iportant in the question, not the comments. Anyhow, the fact that the crash appears at different steps can hint that it is a hardware problem.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm new to the site. Thanks for the heads up. I'll update the question. Everyone seems to think it HW, but I don't know which tests to run anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed on the TI Forum, here is the link for those interested.

https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors-group/processors/f/processors-forum/1158936/am3359-caught-segv-when-distro-s-systemd-starting

In summary, the issue was that my VDD_MPU(1.1V) was driven by my PMIC and the PMIC driver was not properly initialized. Meaning that when the system rose the CPU Freq. to 800MHz, the 1.1V was too low and the MPU would be in brownout and get corrupted. The solution was to either manually raise the VDD_MPU to something higher (under 1.3V) or to configure my PMIC to automatically manage the voltage based on the CPU Freq.